# Finding limit of $m(1-\frac{1}{m+1})^{m^2-m-1}$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Intuitively I feel like the limit is going to 0. But while proving if I take log then it is coming infinity. Please solve the problem.

Comment: Why would you think the limit should be $0$?

Comment: @Suzet Wolfram alpha ahah!

Comment: Because $m^2$ grows much faster than $m$ and hence $(1-\frac{1}{m+1})^{m^2-m-1}$ will go to $0$ much faster than $m$ goes to $\infty$. Hence the whole limit should go to $0$.

Comment: What about writing the expression as the exp of a log, factorizing and using a limited development of log in 0 ?

Comment: Oh right, of course, I feel a little rusty now

Comment: Can anyone provide a formal proof please?

Comment: @Ani Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

By root test we have

$$\sqrt[m]{a_m}=\sqrt[m]m\left(1-\frac{1}{m+1}\right)^{\frac{m^2-m-1}m}\to 1\cdot \frac1e=\frac1e<1$$

indeed

$$\sqrt[m]m=e^{\frac{\log m}m}\to e^0=1$$

and

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{m+1}\right)^{\frac{m^2-m-1}m}=\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{m+1}\right)^{m+1}\right]^\frac{m^2-m-1}{m(m+1)}\to \frac1e$$

therefore

$$a_m=m\left(1-\frac{1}{m+1}\right)^{m^2-m-1}\to 0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never crossed my mind. Was thinking in the direction of finding the limit rigorously.

Comment: @Ani Root test in this case is a very effective way.

Comment: But isn't root test is for the test of convergence of a series?

Comment: @Ani Even if not always clearly pointed out it is of course valid also for sequences. Moreover note that if €$(a_n)^{1/n}\to L <1$ the series $\sum a_n$ converges but then $a_n \to 0$.